# How to do user content from CMS in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to build a CMS in Rails from scratch, and for showing the user generated pages I'm having trouble deciding exactly how to do it.

The way I have it right now, I have a controller named 'content' with a single action called 'show'.  In routes.rb I have a rule that passes any name after the name of the website to the content controller, show action with parameter name.

For example, www.mysite.com/about_us would route to

```
:controller => 'content', :action => 'show', :page => 'about_us'
```

Inside the content controller, I do a find on the Pages model to locate the named page:

```
@markup = Page.find_by_name(params[:page])
```

And then in the show.html.erb view I use the raw helper to display the content:

```
<%= raw @markup.text %>
```

Does this method violate anything about the way I should do be doing things in Rails? Or is this an OK solution?

Comment: `<%= raw @markup.text %>` This allows everyone who has access to your CMS to input malicious javascript code into the content. Just a hint.

Comment: I wondered about that when I put it in there.  My idea was to allow users to format their pages using TinyMCE, which produces markup.  Using 'raw' was the only way I found to get rails to output the markup without escaping the tags.  I also found an method for rails strings called html_safe, but I'm not sure that does exactly what I want it to.

Comment: or what if i use the sanitize helper instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the sanitize helper, by default it removes `<script>` tags which is essentially what you need to prevent XSS, as far as I understand.  For those who have found this via a search, the only code that changes from what I described above is that in the view you change to:

```
<%= sanitize @markup.text %>
```